# Using WMS in FME inspector

Tags: wms, fme-form

I want to use Finland national WMS map (MML Kapsi) as background map in FME inspector. Is it possible? What information is needed?

WMS URL is: http://tiles.kartat.kapsi.fi/peruskartta

[image: WMS option window]

Answer (score 2):

You also have to select one or more subitems:

[image]